# TFS "Could not find a part of the path" after successful get latest and switch to git

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

Using Visual Studio TFS connection, I did a get latest on a number of folders.  Then I needed to work with some Git repos which I also did through Visual Studio.  When I came back and tried to connect to TFS, it gave me the following error:
[image: TFS Error]

I can't see any of the data in TFS.  I have verified that this path exists but I don't know exactly what inside of that folder it might be looking for.

This is the second time in a few days that I've run into this problem.  The first time, I deleted P:\TFS and re-downloaded everything out of TFS but it is a long process due to the amount of source and I'm really looking for a better alternative.

I'm using TFS 2012 from Visual Studio 2015.

Has anyone run into anything similar?  Do you have any suggestions for how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in a workspace mapping, there is a hidden folder named $tf. Maybe your issue is related to your workspace mapping.

You can try to edit your workspace mapping to another local path to monitor whether this issue would happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Try clean \ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces\ folder in system drive

version: VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the Cache folder on your client computer to see whether it is helpful. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.`(x is the version of TFS)

Comment: I tried cleaning the cache folder per your instructions but, unfortunately, I didn't see any change in behavior.